# ansible regex_search with multline strings

Tags: ansible

I have a string that looks like this in stdout

```
    "msg": [
        "--------------------------------------------------------------------------------\nHostname             : switch1\nChassis Type         : 7144-d\nPart Number          : 3HE1RA01\nSerial Number        : 630943\nSystem HW MAC Address: 18:C3:ff:ff:ff:F5\nSoftware Version     : v22.1.1\nBuild Number         : 90-g4b19af2d95\nArchitecture         : x86_64\nLast Booted          : 2023-01-09T19:55:26.679Z\nTotal Memory         : 15987484 kB\nFree Memory          : 13054218 kB\n--------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
    ]
```

i'm trying to use `regex_search` to match only the `Software Version     : v22.1.1` line

my play looks like:

```
- name: Get version
  set_fact:
    version: "{{ show_version.stdout | regex_search('Software Version.*') }}"
```

however this is matching on `Software Version` and everything after that as well.  The debug looks like:

```
{
    "version": "Software Version     : v22.1.1\\nBuild Number         : 90-g4b19af2d95\\nArchitecture         : x86_64\\nLast Booted          : 2023-01-09T19:55:26.679Z\\nTotal Memory         : 15987484 kB\\nFree Memory          : 13054218 kB\\n--------------------------------------------------------------------------------']"
}
```

What am i doing wrong?  I just want this line exactly `Software Version     : v22.1.1`
I thought regex_search is singleline by default.

Comment: i'm confused because in python `re.search('Software Version.*',text)` does exactly what i want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you've got *`show_version.stdout`* in the registered variable you must have got *`show_version.stdout_lines`* as well

```yaml
  show_version.stdout_lines:
  - '-------------------------------------------------'
  - 'Hostname             : switch1'
  - 'Chassis Type         : 7144-d'
  - 'Part Number          : 3HE1RA01'
  - 'Serial Number        : 630943'
  - 'System HW MAC Address: 18:C3:ff:ff:ff:F5'
  - 'Software Version     : v22.1.1'
  - 'Build Number         : 90-g4b19af2d95'
  - 'Architecture         : x86_64'
  - 'Last Booted          : 2023-01-09T19:55:26.679Z'
  - 'Total Memory         : 15987484 kB'
  - 'Free Memory          : 13054218 kB'
  - '-------------------------------------------------'
```

Select the first line that matches the regex if this is all you want

```yaml
  version_line: "{{ show_version.stdout_lines|
                    select('search', 'Software Version.*')|first }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  version_line: 'Software Version     : v22.1.1'
```

In a systemic way create a dictionary. Declare the variables

```yaml
    show_version_dict_str: |
      {% for i in show_version.stdout_lines[1:-1] %}
      {% set kv = i.split(':', 1) %}
      {{ kv.0|trim }}: "{{ kv.1|trim }}"
      {% endfor %}
    show_version_dict: "{{ show_version_dict_str|from_yaml }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  show_version_dict:
    Architecture: x86_64
    Build Number: 90-g4b19af2d95
    Chassis Type: 7144-d
    Free Memory: 13054218 kB
    Hostname: switch1
    Last Booted: '2023-01-09T19:55:26.679Z'
    Part Number: 3HE1RA01
    Serial Number: '630943'
    Software Version: v22.1.1
    System HW MAC Address: 18:C3:ff:ff:ff:F5
    Total Memory: 15987484 kB
```

Get the version

```yaml
  version: "{{ show_version_dict['Software Version'] }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  version: v22.1.1
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    show_version:
      stdout_lines:
        - '-------------------------------------------------'
        - 'Hostname             : switch1'
        - 'Chassis Type         : 7144-d'
        - 'Part Number          : 3HE1RA01'
        - 'Serial Number        : 630943'
        - 'System HW MAC Address: 18:C3:ff:ff:ff:F5'
        - 'Software Version     : v22.1.1'
        - 'Build Number         : 90-g4b19af2d95'
        - 'Architecture         : x86_64'
        - 'Last Booted          : 2023-01-09T19:55:26.679Z'
        - 'Total Memory         : 15987484 kB'
        - 'Free Memory          : 13054218 kB'
        - '-------------------------------------------------'

    version_line: "{{ show_version.stdout_lines|
                      select('search', 'Software Version.*')|first }}"
     
    show_version_dict_str: |
      {% for i in show_version.stdout_lines[1:-1] %}
      {% set kv = i.split(':', 1) %}
      {{ kv.0|trim }}: "{{ kv.1|trim }}"
      {% endfor %}
    show_version_dict: "{{ show_version_dict_str|from_yaml }}"
    version: "{{ show_version_dict['Software Version'] }}"
    
  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: version_line

    - debug:
        var: show_version_dict
    - debug:
        var: version
```